# How to disable sorting of first column of DataTables?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried many ways of disabling sorting on the first column. I have not been able to achieve it.

I have been able to disable all columns beside the first column using:

```
'columnDefs': [ {
'targets': [],
'orderable': false, // set orderable false for selected columns
}]
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 2):

Your `columnDefs.targets` is empty. You have to pass the index of the column where you want to disable sorting. For first column, you need to pass the first column's index, 0.

As per [datatables documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderable), you can disable ordering of first column in two ways:

1. With columnDefs:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [
    { "orderable": false, "targets": 0 }
  ]
} );
```

2. With columns:

```
"columns": [
    { "orderable": false },
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null
]
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/d12a9gxn/ - Works for me, can you share a jsfiddle with your config?

Comment: Where does it work? The sorting icon is still active on the first tab. Did you see?

Comment: Oh, you want to remove the initial default sorting? `aaSorting: []` - This should be passed as a config option. I have removed the initial sort here - http://jsfiddle.net/xom4qdeL/

Comment: Or you will have to do `order: []`

Answer (score 0):

[order](https://datatables.net/reference/option/order) is used to apply initial order (sort) to the table.
It can be used to apply initial sorting on any other column.
By default, DataTables use first column even if you disable sorting for that column using [targets](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs.targets).